# Math110C, Multivariable Calculus, Second Derivatives Test

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Find the local maximum and minimum values and saddle point(s) of the function $f(x,y)=y^2-2y \cos x$, -1<=x<=7:

First, I found the first partial derivatives:

$f_x=-2y(-\sin x)=2y \sin x$ and $f_y=2y-2 \cos x$

so I got $0=-2y(-\sin x)=2y \sin x$ and $0=2y-2 \cos x$

Next, I plugged $0=2y-2 \cos x$ => $2y=2 \cos x$ into $0=2y \sin x$ :

$0=2y \sin x$ => $0=(2 \cos x)\sin x$ => $0=\sin 2x$

Now, I'm not sure how to find the critical points. However, I know the solution should be Minima $f(0,1)=f(\pi,-1)=f(2 \pi,1)=1$ and saddle points at $(\pi/2,0),(3 \pi/2,0)$.

Comment: You can make more effort than this. Surely you can find the values of $x$ so that $\sin 2x = 0$. For these values of $x$, you'll need $y=\cos x$. This gives you ordered pairs, right? Edit your post to incorporate this. Then edit your post to include what the second derivative test is and apply it at all these points.

Comment: Oh!  I see! I failed to notice that I could find the values of x for sin2x =0. Thank you!